# Ordered Group by - Select VS View

Tags: mysql

I got some product table and its images table with 1:N. For simplicity just:

```
create table t_Product(
ID int not null,
Name varchar(255),
primary key (ID)
);
create table t_Images(
ID int not null,
PID int not null,
IsDefault int,
primary key (ID),
foreign key (PID) references t_Product (ID)
);
insert into t_Product (ID, Name) values (1, 'test1');
insert into t_Product (ID, Name) values (2, 'test2');
insert into t_Images (ID, PID, IsDefault) values (1, 1, 1);
insert into t_Images (ID, PID, IsDefault) values (2, 1, 0);
insert into t_Images (ID, PID, IsDefault) values (3, 2, 0);
insert into t_Images (ID, PID, IsDefault) values (4, 2, 1);
```

now I make a select which makes exactly what I need (select default or first image from each product):

```
select
    I.*
from
(
select
    ID,
    PID,
    IsDefault
from
    t_Images
order by
    PID asc,
    IsDefault desc,
    ID asc
) I
group by
    I.PID

ID  PID IsDefault
1   1   1
4   2   1
```

now I make a view from inner select:

```
create view v_Images
as
select
    ID,
    PID,
    IsDefault
from
    t_Images
order by
    PID asc,
    IsDefault desc,
    ID asc
```

but selecting this view applies no ordering when group by:

```
select
    VI.*
from
    v_Images VI
group by
    VI.PID

ID  PID IsDefault
1   1   1
3   2   0
```

but if I select first from this select from view and then group by, it works again:

```
select
    VI2.*
from
(
    select
        VI.*
    from
        v_Images VI
) VI2
group by
    VI2.PID

ID  PID IsDefault
1   1   1
4   2   1
```

could somebody explain me, why grouping select has different result then view, and why it works again on double selected view?

Comment: `set sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select I.*
from (select ID, PID, IsDefault
      from t_Images
      order by PID asc, IsDefault desc, ID asc
     ) I
group by I.PID;
```

Although not an uncommon formulation, it is using a construct that the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) explicitly warns against.  Here is the full text of the relevant part (emphasis is mine):

> ```
> SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)
>   FROM orders AS o, customers AS c
>   WHERE o.custid = c.custid
>   GROUP BY o.custid;
> ```
>
> For the query to be legal, the name column must be omitted from the
>   select list or named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.**

So, although the query may seem to work, the documentation warns against it.  I consider this bad practice.  Plus, this is something that only works in MySQL.  Other databases do not allow this construct.  And, ANSI has similar-ish functionality involving columns with "functional dependencies" and you run the risk that future versions of MySQL will support this reasonable functionality, invalidating this approach.

My advice is to use a reasonable approach that not only performs well in MySQL but is also ANSI compliant.  Something like:

```
select ti.*
from t_Images ti
where not exists (select 1
                  from t_images ti2
                  where ti2.pid = ti.pid and
                        (ti2.IsDefault > ti.IsDefault or
                         (ti2.IsDefault = ti.IsDefault and
                          ti2.Id < ti.Id
                         )
                        )
                 )
```

Or use aggregation with `substring_index()`/`group_concat()`:

```
select pid, max(IsDefault) as IsDefault,
       substring_index(group_concat(id order by isDefault desc id asc), ',', 1) as id
from ti_images
group by pid;
```